# Exclusive consumer for Tibco EMS

Tags: tibco-ems

For ActiveMQ it is possible to create [exclusive consumers](https://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer) for queue so that only one consumer receives all messages while it is alive.

Is it possible to do the same for Tibco EMS? I was able to find only information about [exclusive queues](https://haritibcoblog.com/2017/04/03/tibco-ems-properties-of-queues-and-topics-where-tuning-can-be-done/), but it requires some permissions to manage queue. Is it possible to specify it somehow on client when I'm connecting to an existing queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to create an exclusive consumer on TIBCO EMS without setting the exclusive property on the queue.